# How to access phone connected to wifi and send message through network to said phone with MAC address?

Tags: wireless-networking

Okay so lately someone has been connecting to my wifi and i have no idea who. I know the mac address and model number of the phone, so my question is: IF I am able to, how do i send them a message, or disconnect them completely?

Answer (score 1):

To disconnect them completely, turn on WPA2-PSK and set a strong password.

Answer (score 1):

In your wireless router, there should be an option to block their device via MAC address, this is usually in the security tab or menu, though it can be in different places depending on the make of wireless router, you will also need administrative privileges to said router.